# Advanced conditional & Low Variable parse order

Tags: parse-order, low-variables

I need to use an advanced conditional with [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) and am having trouble getting it to work. I believe it's a parse order thing but am not sure how to get around it.

I am checking the current date/time against 2 Low Variables to see if the current date/time is in between 2 variables.

```
{if '{current_time format="%F %d - %g:%i %a"}' >= '{date_start}' AND '{current_time format="%F %d - %g:%i %a"}' <= '{date_end}'}
Show some content
{/if}
```

date_start & date_end are the Low Variables & I have both of them set to parse early.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conditional will never work because the format you chose. "%F %d - %g:%i %a" isn't a number and just numbers can use `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=`.

You need to [format](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html#date-formatting-codes) all variables used in this conditionals as seconds since [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).

```
{if {current_time format="%U"} >= {date_start} AND {current_time format="%U"} <= {date_end} }
  Show some content
{/if}
```

Remember that your Low Variables need to be formated this way too! If you can't, there are some addons which can change the format of a date. [Low has one](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date/).

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{date_start}" format="%U"}
```

So:

```
{if {current_time format="%U"} >= {exp:low_nice_date date="{date_start}" format="%U"} AND {current_time format="%U"} <= {exp:low_nice_date date="{date_end}" format="%U"} }
  Show some content
{/if}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! It does make it a little more difficult for the client to edit this since they have to provide the seconds since Epoch. Any thoughts on making this easier for them?

Comment: Sure! I gonna update my answer.